# How do I keep my angular project synchronized with GitHub?

Tags: angular, git, github

What I know is that we have to do "ng build" each time before commit. But is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `git fetch` and `git pull`

Comment: Why would you do a build before commit? what are you trying to achieve by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

To do this, place a file named `pre-commit` in the `.git/hooks` directory inside your git repository. In that file, you can write a script to run your build, and this will run each time you try to commit, before the commit.